# C# ValidateRequest Work Around

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I have one textbox in my entire app that I want to be able to accept html.  I don't really want to go through all my pages and add Server.HtmlEncode(textbox.Text).

Is there a work around.  I'm using C# and asp.net 4.0 and I know the ValidateRequest stuff changed in 4.0 but I don't know if it can solve my problem.  Can it?

Comment: Does the textbox belong to only one page/form of the app...or is it recurring in multiple pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always mark validateRequest=false at page level. So you can try that on the page containing that particular text-box